# "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" is Broken

Tags: bug

I am having issues with the "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" setting. I set the MOQ to be 25 units, within the inventory setting for a specific product. I can then add 25 units to my shopping cart. The problem is that when I try to add more than 25 units, for example, 26 or 50 units, **my shopping cart always reverts back to 25 units.**

I do not have Qty Increments enabled. I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 Community Edition. How can this bug be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that you accidentally didn't do **Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** instead? Did you try to do 15 qty?

Also you have the ability to set this on the product level as well as the global level. Check system configuration under the Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options.